# SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor does not log for remote endpoint

Tags: spring-ws

I'm wondering why SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor does not log the requests/responses for an endpoint configured as a service on a remote JVM while it works just fine if configured against localhost.

Any ideas?

- Pawel

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that could cause this issue. Without any code or any details about what technologie you use for logging (i.e log4 etc...), it will be difficult for anybody to answer your question. If you're using log4j, you may want to compare your local configuration versus your remote server configuration to detect what the difference is.